# Avoid the alert when my app receives a local notification while in background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, localnotification

Is there a way to avoid displaying the initial alert when my app receives a local notification while in the background or closed?

I want the local notification to go directly to AppDelegate method, bypassing any alert. Is this possible?

Basically, I want my app to run a certain code on the reception of the Local Notification, without needing any user action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Local or remote notifications cannot launch apps (or bring them to the foreground) without user interaction.

Comment: Crap. :-( Is there any workaround you know of? I need some code to be run whenever an Event (from EventKit) is fired.